# Fitting Font Size to Enclosing Button?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I have buttons in my Xcode project that scale with screen size. They are all squares. Initially, when I switched the display to iPad, the buttons would scale properly but the text would stay the same size. Then, I added these lines and set the preset font to the size that fit iPad. Then, the font would scale down based on smaller devices. However, on smaller devices, there would be a huge space above the text.

```
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byClipping;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDMVX.jpg  || you can see the extra padding on top. I want the text to be properly sized (already accomplished) and also centered amongst the button. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide example project or sufficient info to all us to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the font for the button title to a very large one, and then would set the minimum font scale to some thing like 0.1 or 0.2. Like this:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50) //for example
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1 // you don't want it to split into 2 rows, right?
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

The **minimumScaleFactor** is making sure your label text will autoshrink, in regards of your button's frame, maximum until it is 10% from your initial scale you set.

**UPDATE**:

Add this line to make the text appear in the center:

```
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center // or .justified (try it yourself)
```

Although, your image is so unclear. What is the gray area? If the whole square is your button, and the gray is an image, then you need to notice that the text appear to be in the middle of the square, which leads to the conclusion that your image is wrong. Its hole isn't in the center where the text should be.

Comment: The problem persists. The text resizes properly except theres a huge space above the text as seen in this image : https://imgur.com/8KEiJxj